# Play framework, Less output coming as empty file

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, less

I am working on a simple project on play, Idea and scala, I have "Less code" in :
app/assets/stylesheets

```
@pale-green-color: #4D926F;
@pale-blue-color: #CFECEC;
h1 {
  color: @pale-green-color;
}
h2 {
  color: @pale-blue-color;
}   `
```

I see an empty file when I inspect on browser as assets/home.css. any idea?
Though I right click and run as play On IntelliJ idea, I see compilation successfully.

Comment: If you look from intellij in public/stylesheets, do you see your compiled .css file? If not, have a look in project/plugins.sbt and make sure you have the line addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0")

Comment: No I dont see .css file, even I dont see .js file, for which I am writing coffee script, yeah I have following line: addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.0")

Comment: How are you referring to your stylesheet from within your template? Can you post your main.scala.html file?